# There was an error checking the latest version of pip - Docker Desktop tutorial

Tags: windows, docker-desktop

Recently I installed latest Docker Desctop version on my Windows 10 laptop.
Docker Desktop 4.11.1 (84025)
I am trying to run tutorial I am getting the following issue

```
docker build -t docker101tutorial .
[+] Building 17.6s (12/24)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                  0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.12kB                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 52B                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                                       3.1s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:alpine                                                                                      3.7s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12-alpine                                                                                     3.3s 
 => CACHED [stage-6 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:082f8c10bd47b6acc8ef15ae61ae45dd8fde0e9f389a8b5cb23c37408642bf5d                  0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                     0.4s 
 => => transferring context: 10.45MB                                                                                                                  0.4s 
 => CANCELED [app-base 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12-alpine@sha256:d4b15b3d48f42059a15bd659be60afe21762aae9d6cbea6f124440895c27db68            13.8s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:12-alpine@sha256:d4b15b3d48f42059a15bd659be60afe21762aae9d6cbea6f124440895c27db68                               0.0s 
 => => sha256:4517380049fc3c9aacceae7764fcf3500354b0ac8a47e4afb35b5bbeb75b9498 1.16kB / 1.16kB                                                        0.0s 
 => => sha256:bb6d28039b8cec9aa8d9032f9aa640a792a60c2cb1644691627bf046aab27c8b 6.58kB / 6.58kB                                                        0.0s 
 => => sha256:df9b9388f04ad6279a7410b85cedfdcb2208c0a003da7ab5613af71079148139 2.81MB / 2.81MB                                                        2.1s 
 => => sha256:3bf6d738020517f4622814e8c21db4b4aaa78ae7cab4e4f872c11696886c6285 3.15MB / 24.91MB                                                      13.7s 
 => => sha256:7939e601ee5e4737cf7fdb6d1dfe31ca4c2697109290462f694710761450aef0 2.36MB / 2.36MB                                                        2.1s 
 => => sha256:d4b15b3d48f42059a15bd659be60afe21762aae9d6cbea6f124440895c27db68 1.43kB / 1.43kB                                                        0.0s 
 => => extracting sha256:df9b9388f04ad6279a7410b85cedfdcb2208c0a003da7ab5613af71079148139                                                             0.4s 
 => => sha256:31f0fb9de071269230cb0f786012ae4e81d26e489b1fe922e57b5201e6bc9ab0 451B / 451B                                                            2.2s 
 => [base 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:0c46c7f15ee201a2e2dc3579dbc302f989a20b1283e67f884941e071372eb2cc                           0.0s 
 => CACHED [base 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => CACHED [base 3/4] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => ERROR [base 4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                             13.4s 
------
 > [base 4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt:
#21 5.174 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationE
rror(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/mkdocs/
#21 5.750 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationE
rror(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/mkdocs/
#21 6.829 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationE
rror(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/mkdocs/
#21 8.951 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationE
rror(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/mkdocs/
#21 13.02 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationE
rror(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/mkdocs/
#21 13.11 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/mkdocs/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', por
t=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/mkdocs/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
 failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
#21 13.11 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkdocs==1.3.0 (from versions: none)
#21 13.12 ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkdocs==1.3.0
#21 13.21 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=4
43): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify faile
d: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
#21 13.22 WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

I installed latest version of Python but it didn't help.